# Scroll DIV which contains image, not Document

Tags: html, css

I have a large image within a div which i want to scroll. But instead of the div scrolling, i have the document scrolling.

**How can i get the image to scroll within the DIV and NOT the parent or document?**

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Force Scroll</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .scrollable 
        {
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="scrollable">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="test image" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set a (max) width and height for the div and it should work. Otherwise the div will just adjust itself to the size of the image:

```
#mydiv {
  overflow: auto;

  max-width: 800px;  // or width instead of max-width
  max-height: 600px; // or height instead of max-height
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/x58RD/.

---

If it happens that you are forced to support ancient browsers like IE6, you need to use `width` and `height` instead of `max-width` and `max-height` anyways or it still won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a width and height.  Divs are block elements and will take up as much space as needed.  In this case as large as the image is.

Answer (score 1):

you need to fix size of div, for example:

```
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
```