# Tricky CSS : crop image without direct container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm currently struggling on a tricky CSS problem thant I cannot resolve. I would like to build an **img** (two-by-two on two lines) controller which can display :

- the top-left image in full-size,
- the top-right in *overflow-x: scroll* (or auto, etc.),
- the bottom-left in *overflow-y: scroll* (...),
- the bottom-right with both.

**A little bit like the Excel fix columns/lines feature.**

My HTML :

```
    <div id="global">
        <div id="feature-container">
            <div id="feature-head">
                <img id="feature-t-l" src="..." alt="..."/>
                <img id="feature-t-l" src="..." alt="..."/>
            </div>
            <div id="feature-body">
                <img id="feature-b-l" src="..." alt="..."/>
                <img id="feature-b-r" src="..." alt="..."/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS :

```
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    html body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 8px 0 8px;
      background-color: darkgrey;
    }
    html body h1 {
      height: 10%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding-top: 2%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
    }
    html body #global {
      height: 90%;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      padding: 0% 2.5% 5% 2.5%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html body #global #feature-container {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: white;
    }
    html body #global #feature-container #feature-header {
      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    html body #global #feature-container #feature-header > img {
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    html body #global #feature-container #feature-header img#feature-t-l {
      overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    html body #global #feature-container #feature-body {
      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Currently, the top-left *img* isn't cropped. Even with the *max-size* on *#global*, the *overflow-x* on the top-left. It is possible to resolve this **without using px** ?

Edit: Thanks to Fausto NA, a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xve5jakh/). On my project, the two top *img* are on the same line and there is no blank between the head and the body.

Comment: Make a JSFiddle with placeholder images like this: https://jsfiddle.net/r0vLysmg/ and specify their size so we can help you better.

Comment: I did, but for me the two top *img* are on the same line and there is no blank between head and body.

Comment: What? You didn't read my comment...

Comment: Sorry, I have never use this tool before. I updated without forking. I edited my message, and [here is the link](https://jsfiddle.net/xve5jakh/).

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what exactly it is you want to do. Sorry :(

Comment: In an unrelated note, may I suggest that your CSS selectors are overly specific?

Comment: This is a .less conversion

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: no. As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521798/scroll-div-which-contains-image-not-document) explains, you need to set the width or height of a DIV or else it will auto-size to its IMG child. Also, you'll need to put a scrolling DIV around each IMG, if you want them to have each IMG to have its own scrolling.

The long answer: you should review your understanding of CSS. `html body #global #feature-container #feature-container` means "apply this style to a `#feature-container` that is some indirect child of another `#feature-container`, which is an indirect child of a `#global`, which is an indirect... And you have not `#feature-container` that is a child of another `#feature-container`. There are other CSS rules that don't match anything in your HTML, like `img#feature-container`.

Conclusion: how's this?

https://jsfiddle.net/xve5jakh/1/